# Parse: Facebook user unlink and login again creates two user table entries

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I see that my parse login through Facebook code looks like this.

```
PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {
                println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
                let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
                graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

                    if ((error) != nil)
                    {
                        println("Error: \(error)")
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        let userEmail : NSString = result.valueForKey("email") as! NSString
                        println("User Email is: \(userEmail)")
                        user["email"] = userEmail
                    }
                })
            } else {
                println("User logged in through Facebook!")
            }
        } else {
            println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
        }
    }
```

Logout method looks like this

```
PFFacebookUtils.unlinkUserInBackground(PFUser.currentUser()!) { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if succeeded {
            FBSDKAccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(nil)
            FBSDKProfile.setCurrentProfile(nil)
            PFUser.logOut()
        } else {
            println("Error")
        }
    }
```

When the user logs in the first time, I see that the parse creates a row in the user table with authData pointing to Facebook. Upon logging out, this authData is erased.

The problem is when the user logs in again, parse creates another row and links the authData pointing to Facebook, is there a way to avoid this. I want to use the same row created before and link to the Facebook login instead of creating multiple rows every time the user logs out and login.

I could check if an email already exists, but for that I need the email of the user logging in again and when that happens, a new row is already created.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to link the user to a facebook account, the code below does this link for you:

```
if !PFFacebookUtils.isLinkedWithUser(user) {
  PFFacebookUtils.linkUserInBackground(user, withReadPermissions: nil, {
    (succeeded: Bool?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if succeeded {
      println("Woohoo, the user is linked with Facebook!")
    }
  })
}
```

[From Parse.com documentation:](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-facebook-users)

> The steps that happen when linking are very similar to log in. The
>   difference is that on successful login, the existing PFUser is updated
>   with the Facebook information. Future logins via Facebook will now log
>   in the user to their existing account.

Comment: True, the same page also tells this - Our SDK receives the user's Facebook access data and saves it to a PFUser. If no PFUser exists with the same Facebook ID, then a new PFUser is created. This explains the reason why a new row was created in my case.

Comment: @sysuser that is it, I am glad you got it, good luck with your app!

Comment: Thanks, the doc made it easy.

Comment: Where do I call this `isLinkedWithUser` code? Also, do I call both that and `loginInBackground`..

Comment: Since for this call `FFacebookUtils.linkUserInBackground(user, withReadPermissions: nil, {` you need to pass in the `user` object, at that point, the new user entry has already been created in the User table in Parse.. I don't see how this solves the problem?